# Find out if a given string is Salesforce Id in Java

Tags: salesforce-id, mobile, regular-expressions

Is there a way(regex or something) to find out if a given string is a Salesforce Id or not? I'm looking for some helper class in Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regex is okay: `[A-Za-z0-9]{15}`

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class IdUtil {
  private static final String INPUT = "00a000000000012";
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern id = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z0-9]{15}");
    Matcher matcher = id.matcher(INPUT);
    if (!matcher.find()) System.out.println("Not an Id!");
  }
}
```

If you use "[A-Za-z0-9]{18}" to find 18-character Ids (case-insensitive), best to run the checksum as well. You could port [this implementation](http://astadiaemea.wordpress.com/2010/06/21/15-or-18-character-ids-in-salesforce-com-%E2%80%93-do-you-know-how-useful-unique-ids-are-to-your-development-effort/) of the algorithm to Java.

Answer (score 1):

Apex Id data type does validate what is set into it, In apex, you could assign a string to an Id type variable. If you put that in a try block and catch StringException the catch block will indicate failure.

```
String anIdString = 'a05E0000002Ug8U'; //also works with a05E0000002Ug8UIAS
String aString = 'whatever';

Id anId = anIdString;

System.debug(anId);

try {
    anId = aString;
} catch (StringException e) {
    System.debug('tried to assign invalid string to Id and failed');
}
System.debug(anId);
```

**EDIT:** If you wanted to access that logic from outside of SFDC, you could write the logic into a custom webservice method. Even though this is a very clean way to do Id datatype checking, it has the downside of consuming a webservice call for very little gain. But it could be scaled perhaps to do the same with an array of strings:

```
global with sharing class DemoWebService {
webService static Boolean isStringId(String idTestStr) {
    Boolean isId = true;
    Id anId;
    try {
        anId = idTestStr;
    } catch (StringException e) {
        isId = false;
    }
    return isId;
}
}
```

Comment: Shoot...didn't read the Java bit.

Comment: You could still do sth like that in Java (pass something to Id field, send a DML, watch fireworks). It should fail on XML composition phase before reaching SF; if I recall correctly XSD has validation of 15/18 chars, alphanumeric only. Not too sophisticated but it's something, not sure how many cycles OP wishes to spend on essentially checking it twice...

Comment: It would be the ultimate in API-call-wasting to take a trip to the server just to validate an ID is an ID. But you could take the code above and wrap it in a webservice method...I'll take a shot.

Comment: haha, at least this will work if salesforce ever decides to change the ID structure.

Comment: Not likely. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match 15 and 18-character ids at the same time then use reqular expression pattern:

`[a-zA-Z0-9]{15}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{18}`